# Are there any known noncomputability proofs that do not rely on the halting problem?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I have looked around and thought of this for a while, and I have not found or been able to construct any proof that a problem is not decidable, without said proof being fundamentally equivalent to showing that an algorithm for solving the problem yields an algorithm for solving the halting problem. Is anyone aware of an undecidability proof (for a problem, not a theorem) that does not rely on drawing a contradiction through solving the halting problem?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, as became clear in the answer given below, that I am interested in problems of the form "determine if x is a member of S", where S is a recursively enumerable set. The standard proof of the halting problem itself is a diagonal argument, and so other proofs using that technique are likely. However, as far as I know, the technique has not been used on recursively enumerable sets. I work so exclusively with recursively enumerable sets that it did not even occur to me to mention this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No natural example of a noncomputable set of degree strictly below that of the halting problem is known - let alone an r.e. example.

However, it is known that such examples exist, if we drop the "natural" requirement:

> There are r.e. sets A, B such that neither is Turing reducible to the other.

This is the *Friedberg-Muchnik theorem*. Moreover, the proof is *constructive*. So perhaps that provides an example.

Optimistically, there is always the possibility that such a natural degree exists, which we just don't know about. While this seems extremely unlikely, there's nothing really ruling it out - for example, it's possible that Hilbert's 10th problem, over $\mathbb{Q}$, provides such an intermediate degree! (Over $\mathbb{R}$ it is computable - this is due to Tarski - and over $\mathbb{N}$ it is of course the halting problem in disguise - Matiyasevich/Robinson/Davis/Putnam)

---

On the other hand, there are several results that suggest that there is no natural intermediate degree. For instance, there is no Turing functional $\Phi_e$ which is Turing invariant ($A\equiv_TB\implies \Phi_e^A\equiv_T\Phi_e^B$) and satisfies $X<_T\Phi_e^X<_TX'$ for all $X$.

Moreover, it is conjectured (Martin's conjecture) that every Borel Turing-invariant function is "essentially an iterate of the Turing jump" in a precise sense; and that, under the Axiom of Determinacy, **every** Turing-invariant function is essentially an iterate of the Turing jump.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $S$ of all one-argument integer functions computed by Turing machines under some protocol.  (Like “The input and output are in base 2,” etc.)  The set of all machines is enumerable, so the subset that calculate integer functions is enumerable.  Enumerate $S$, and let $f_i$ be the function calculated by the $i$th machine in $S$.  Then

$$g(n) = f_n(n)+1$$
is not computable.

Comment: How do you define integer functions? For example, if we are studying Turing machines under some first order theory, we can recursively enumerate all provably halting integer functions, with provability interpreted as provable from the contextual theory. With a recursive enumeration of the f_i, and with all f_i halting (which is necesary for well definiteness), then g is computable.

Comment: It seems to me that if you believe that, then you should also believe that there is no recursive enumeration of provably-halting integer functions, in which case that is also an answer to your question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying I should not beleive that g would be computable if the f_i were provably halting Turing machines representing integer functions according to some protocol. Since proofs are recursively enumerable, provable statements are, and so are Turing machines that are provably halting in some specific theory (i.e., (axioms -> machine M halts) & machine M matches the protocol for an integer function). So the f_i are recursively enumerable, as they are the M's from the preceding statement. One simply produces the list of f_i until f_n is found, then gets f_n(n).

Comment: I work exclusively with recursively enumerable sets, to the point that I did not even see what you were saying. You are saying that since g is one of the f_i, computability of g produces a contradiction. I have edited my question to focus on recursively enumerable sets.

Comment: @user28111, all halting Turing machines corresponding to integer functions do not form an enumerable collection as far as I know, and that is why g in this answer is not an example of a proof that membership in some enumerable set is not computable, which proof does not rely on the halting problem. Without the enumerability condition, which I failed to include at first when this answer was given, this answer would be perfect.